# Best Route from Zurich Airport to Rhine Falls

Tags: public-transport, europe, switzerland, zurich, rhine

I want to go to Rhine Falls from the airport and return to Zurich on the same day. In Zurich, I want to reach the Technopark to be exact.

I am looking for the best and cheapest route to do a round trip to and from Rhine Falls and then reach Technopark (inter-city travel). On Sunday, I will have to go back to the airport form there.

Which tickets/pass should I buy?

Any recommendations?

Comment: After you return, perhaps edit in a remark about how the trip went, what you used to get there and comments about the falls?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As for the ticket you can get a [9 o'clock day pass](https://www.zvv.ch/zvv/en/travelcards-and-tickets/tickets/9-oclock-daypass.html) at the ticket machine at the station in the Airport (the machines are on the floor above the rails). It is valid on all trains, busses and trams within the [ZVV area](https://www.zvv.ch/content/dam/zvv/abos-und-tickets/zonen/tarifzonen.pdf) until 5am the next morning. If you take one of the special night busses/trains running after midnight you need to get an night supplement for CHF 5 (from a ticket machine, you can't buy the supplement in the bus/train).

For the route you want to travel from "Zürich Flughafen" to "Schloss Laufen, Rheinfall". There are several connections per hour, use [ZVV Connections](https://online.fahrplan.zvv.ch/bin/query.exe/en.html) to find the one which suits your arrival. Just make sure you get a connection via Winterthur (the website will also list connections via Bülach and Schaffhausen which isn't covered by the 9 o'clock pass).

[The station is right on top of the fall](https://map.search.ch/?pos=688337,281326&zoom=18), you will have to walk about 60m down to get to the [ferry](https://rhyfall-maendli.ch/en/home/) running between both sides of the river and the little island/rock in the middle of the fall.

[image]

For the trip back, you can either take the train to "Zürich,  Hardbrücke" and walk a few minutes, or the train to Zurich and the tram to "Zürich, Technopark". Just make sure you take a route running via "Winterthur", the ones via "Bülach" aren't covered by the day pass.

PS: Please be aware that wearing a mask is currently mandatory in all public transport in Switzerland.

PPS: For the trip on Sunday, just get a one-way ticket to the airport (three zones) at the ticket machine where you get into the tram/train.

PPPS: If you don't want to worry about finding ticket machines etc you could also use the [ZVV App](https://www.zvv.ch/zvv/en/service/apps/ticket-app.html) to get the pass and individual tickets.

Comment: Are the IR trains also covered by this day pass? For example, I searched for 11:30 on 18th September. I see 3 routes and the first one includes an IR train (marked as red). The next one has a change at Neuhausen and then another one has a change at Zürich Oerlikon (SBB). So, can I take any of these?

Comment: Once I reach  "Schloss Laufen, Rheinfall", how far is the actual Rhein Falls locations where I can take boats etc? If I search on Google maps, it shows a further 30 mins.

Comment: Note that "Neuhausen Rheinfall" might also be a good option for the final stop (though I'm not sure this is covered in the 9o'clock-ticket). Both stops are located within minutes of the Rheinfall. I don't know what Google maps returned for your search, but most certainly not the station mentioned by @nohillside.

Comment: The trains leaving at 11:46 and 11:57 are fine. The one leaving at 12:04 requires you to change trains twice and runs through Germany between Bülach and Schaffhausen. As far as I know this isn't covered by the 9 o'clock pass.

Comment: Why do you think it would be a better stop? https://rheinfall.ch/en/experience/experience/attractions/rhyfall-mandli.html Do you know if I can take any of these boat rides from Schloss Laufen, Rheinfall or just some or none? Or are they only operated from Neuhausen Rheinfall?  @Sabine

Comment: The boats operate both from the left side (Schloss Laufen) and the right side (Schloss Wörth), they do *not* operate from Neuhausen (which is actually on the upper side of the fall). Also Neuhausen is not covered by the 9 o'clock pass.

Comment: I wasn't saying it was better, just another good stop, depending on your actual plans. As an example, the "rock tour" only leaves from Schloss Wörth AFAIK, which is closer to Neuhausen Rheinfall. But crossing the Rhine from Schloss Laufen shouldn't take more than a few minutes, so given that only Schloss Laufen is covered by the 9 o'clock pass, this is probably the better option for you.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you know if there's any other interesting spot that I can stop by on my way back to Zurich?

Comment: Nature, history, something else you have in mind? Taking a trip up to Uetliberg from Zurich Main Station might be something (assuming the weather stays good). The trains leave every 30 minutes, they are included in the 9 o‘clock pass.